# Filter Algolia items based on a string attribute? [InstantSearch]

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm trying to make a work around to a multi-language search different than [this options](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/full-text-search/multi-language-search/multilingual-search/), I have a field in my records 'language', I now I can filter based on a timestamp, i.e:

```
filters: 'timestamp < 1532681390'
```

But I cannot get this to work:

```
filters: 'language:en_us'
```

Am I missing somethign? Do I need to add *language* someplace else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created an index per language as the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/full-text-search/multi-language-search/multilingual-search/?language=instantsearchjs#option-1-one-index-per-language) say. :) Still open to suggestions.